# Convert IList<IList<int>> to a single flattened hashset

Tags: c#, list, casting, ienumerable

I have a list of list with data like :

```
megalist = { new List {1,2}, new List {1,2}, new List{3}};
```

Now, I want to convert this list of `IList` into a single flattened `hashset` that should look like:

```
set = { 1,2,3 }
```

I tried doing 
`megalist.Cast<ISet<int>>().SelectMany(sublist => sublist);` but that returns error:

> Unable to cast object of type 'System.Collections.Generic.List'1[System.Int32]' to type 'System.Collections.Generic.ISet'1[System.Int32]'.

Is something wrong with the approach?
Many thanks.

Comment: `Is something wrong with the approach?` Yes. You cannot cast an `List<T>` (or `IList<T>`) to an `ISet<T>` because these two things are (or represent things that are) quite different in nature from each other...

Comment: Suggestion: Flatten the `IList<IList<T>>` first and then feed the result into a new `HashSet<T>`.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> Is something wrong with the approach?

That's an odd question to ask since plainly you already know the answer. Yes, that is the wrong approach because it will crash at runtime.

A `Cast<T>` operator means that each element of the outer list must **actually be**  of type `T`, and a list is not a set.

Take a step back.  What do you have?  A sequence of sequences.  What do you want? A set.  What do you have at your disposal that gets a set out the back end?  [A method ToHashSet that turns sequences into sets](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.tohashset?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=netframework-4.7.2#System_Linq_Enumerable_ToHashSet__1_System_Collections_Generic_IEnumerable___0__).

Think about sequence operations as **workflows**.

```
Sequence of sequences --first step--> SOMETHING --second step--> Set
```

Work from back to front. The second step is "sequence turns into set".  Therefore "SOMETHING" must be "sequence":

```
Sequence of sequences -first step-> Sequence -ToHashSet-> Set
```

Now we need a step that turns a sequence of sequences into a sequence. You know how to do that:

```
Sequence of sequences --SelectMany--> Sequence --ToHashSet--> Set
```

And now you can write the code:

```
ISet<int> mySet = megalist.SelectMany(x => x).ToHashSet();
```

And you're done.

---

Quick update: Luca notes in a comment that `ToHashSet` is not available in all versions of .NET.  If you don't have it, it's a one-liner to write yourself:

```
static class MyExtensions
{
  public static HashSet<T> ToHashSet<T>(this IEnumerable<T> items)
  {
    return new HashSet<T>(items);
  }
}
```

Comment: `ToHashSet` is only availble in .NET Framework 4.7.2. In case you require a previous version of the .NET Framework, you can make use of the proper [HashSet constructor](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.hashset-1.-ctor?view=netframework-4.7.2#System_Collections_Generic_HashSet_1__ctor_System_Collections_Generic_IEnumerable__0__) that takes a sequence as input.